# Azure API Management

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-api-management

I am using Azure API management which has a link to a third party forum (Discourse). The default login system provided by the api management is been used for signing users up. I want to know if its possible to use single sign on for both api management and the forum so users don't have to make seperate accounts for them. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: welp, I'm not a biggest expert at this, but when you auth to API Management you are probably using an oAuth 2.0 token, so if you make the forum accept the same token it would work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but it seems that we can use AAD ( you won't need to create accounts if you already have them in your AAD ) to log in into API Management.